# Delete IPs from an interface?

Tags: python

I want to delete IPs from an interface when I pass the interface to a function, in this example eth0 is passed in.

I was thinking of calling bash to do so and implementing this command:

```
 ip addr show dev eth0 | grep inet | (while read a b c; do del $b; done)
```

How would I go about this in the best pythonic sense, `os.system`, `subprocess.popen`? Is there some other way of dealing with this that would be preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find IP-addresses you can use python module `netifaces`,
but to del them you need to run `ip` anyway.

Direct translation of your script to Python looks like this:

```
for line in subprocess.Popen(
              ["ip", "addr", "show", "dev", "eth0"],
              stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines():
  if 'inet' in line:
     subprocess.Popen(["ip", "addr", "del", line.split()[1], "dev", "eth0"])
```

Of course you need to add different error checks and exception handling to make your code stable.

Comment: I get the general idea thanks. I did get 'str' has no attribute readlines from your code though!

Comment: @Paul: Oh, sorry, `splitlines` of course. And thank you for the tip!!